# Minimalist window decorations etc in OpenBox or similar

Tags: arch-linux, appearance, openbox

I am currently customising my netbook's ArchLinux install. I really like the minimalist basic style of things like the ThinMC window borders in Gnome, and the FullFlat  Firefox theme. What options are available to recreate this look on something like OpenBox or LXDE? (This is a small netbook, so I want to avoid installing loads of Gnome packages...)

[I asked this question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/175065/flat-basic-minimalist-window-decorations-with-openbox-or-similar) earlier, but perhaps this is a better place for it...]

Comment: I'm not familiar without what you're talking about. I always liked fluxbox better and it seemed to do more... maybe it can do what you want? I haven't been minimalist in years now... I finally succumbed to the call of KDE.

Comment: This is minimalist in a purely aesthetic sense. I linked to the themes I mentioned in the SU question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For saving display space on a netbook, you may want to take a look at a **tiling window manager**, such as [wmii](http://wmii.suckless.org/). On my notebook, a venerable Thinkpad R50e, wmii proves *very* helpful.

EDIT:

If you are more interested in minimalistic-looking themes, you could take a look at a [Themes pages for Fluxbox.](http://customize.org/fluxbox) or one for [OpenBox](http://customize.org/openbox). As I recall, themes such as `Elfin2` are quite minimalistic and do *not* require any additional dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [dwm](http://dwm.suckless.org) for a long time on my netbook. Its a tiling window manager written in about 2k lines of C. Configuration is done through rewriting config.h and making a changes here & there to suit your needs, build again and install.

Its *very*  *very* light weight. [snapshot](http://is.gd/er1b8) netbook attached on 22".

Take a look at [DWM showoff](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=74599) on Arch BBS.

[My Dwm config](http://github.com/ideamonk/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/dwm-5.8.2/config.h) - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> - browser, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>{left/right/up/down}</kbd> music, volume control, etc